# Why is an attempted violent crime judged less harshly than a successful one?

Tags: legal-history

There exist crimes that bring great damage to the victim, such as murder, rape, aggravated assault, theft, etc. If anything had escaped that list, I'm sure it's intuitive what that would be.

In most law systems I'm familiar with, an attempted crime is seen as deserving a lesser punishment than a properly executed one. Yet it eludes me as to why it would be so - if one is shooting another with the intent to murder them, and through sheer luck of having an inept murderer does the victim survive (the same is applied for any other heinous crime), why should the murderer-to-be's "attempted murder" sentence be any lighter than a "murder" one? To me, this seems like a flaw of the system that lets inadequate criminals get lighter sentences just because they're awful at committing crimes.

How did law evolve to bear the distinction in sentencing between the two?

Comment: Maybe this is too philosophical to be answerable here. But just thinking about it for a moment -- a criminal who attempted say, several robberies but never actually succeeded in any, seems less dangerous to society than a criminal who attempted several and succeeded every time. So the sentence should probably reflect that distinction.

Comment: This is more of a "why is this the law?" question than a "what is the law?" question. If the community decides to close this question as off-topic, then it could be asked on Politics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Are you sure your assertion is true. At least in New South Wales the punishment for murder and attempted murder is the same - 25 years. For this to be an answered, I think you need to give some examples of where this actually happens - either on the statute books or in practice in sentencing.

Comment: @DaleM is right here. There are some people who get off easy for whatever reason, but that does not mean it's a rule that you have to get off easy.

Comment: In the United States, at least, the above statements by DaleM and @Putvi aren’t correct. I’m unfamiliar with New South Wales, though. Although the punishment can vary by jurisdiction, attempted murder usually comes with a sentence of approximately half that of a conviction for murder. Likewise, while the death penalty is available in some states for murder convictions, it is not available anywhere for attempted murder convictions. 1st degree attempted murder will often come with a life sentence, but with the possibility of parole.

Comment: @A.fm. I worked in criminal justice for over 10 years, just because the sentences handed out for these crimes is usually less, that does not mean it has to be.

Comment: @A.fm. As far as attempted murder, my state, IL has tougher penalties for attempted murder than murder itself in some circumstances.

Comment: Theoretically, there doesn’t “have to be” a punishment at all. But there is. And although there doesn’t “have to be” a lesser punishment for attempted murder vs murder, there is. The difference is significant not only in the punishments available, but also what lesser offense a defense attorney may try to have the charge reduced to. Both from a practical and statutory point of view, there will hardly ever - if ever - be a time or jurisdiction where attempted murder and murder carry the same weight (non-USA jurisdictions notwithstanding).

Comment: In which circumstances? Please demonstrate.